# Custom naming of files in Python using pathlib library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib, python-os

With the os library you can pass a variable to os.path.join as a file name when creating the file.

```
file_name = "file.txt"
folder_with_files = os.getcwd()
with open(os.path.join(folder_with_files,f"{file_name}.txt"),'w') as file:
    file.write("fail")
```

Is there any way to have the same functionality with the pathlib library?  The following, not suprisingly, doesn't work.

```
with Path.cwd() / Path(f"{file_name}.txt").open('w') as file:
    file.write("fail")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
   with Path.cwd() / Path(f"{file_name}.txt").open('w') as file:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'WindowsPath' and '_io.TextIOWrapper
```

(using Python 3.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis, otherwise it will execute the `.open()` method before it adds the paths together:

```
with (Path.cwd() / Path(f"{file_name}.txt")).open('w') as file:
```

This will work as well:

```py
with open(Path.cwd() / Path(f"{file_name}.txt"), 'w') as file:
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to concatenate (with the `/` operator) a `Path` object (`Path.cwd()`) and a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object (`Path(f"{file_name}.txt").open('w')`). You want to call `.open()` on the concatenated path instead, using parentheses `()`:

```
with (Path.cwd() / Path(f"{file_name}.txt")).open('w') as file:
    file.write("This works!")
```